# MySQL select from specific values

Tags: jquery, mysql, database

I'm trying to do a query that will turn a list of literal values into a result set, but I can't quite figure out the syntax without doing a union.

Here are a couple things I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM (1, 2, 3, 5, 6) temp(id);

select x.* from 
(('test-a1', 'test-a2'), ('test-b1', 'test-b2'), ('test-c1', 'test-c2')) x(col1, col2);
```

Something like that where I'm expecting a result set that looks like:

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
etc…
```

or

```
col1 | col2
test-a1, test-a2
test-b1, test-b2
test-c1, test-c2
etc…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_id_table
( id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO temp_id_table ( id ) VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
;

select id from temp_id_table;
```

results:

```html
id
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table, insert those values to the temp table then query your temp table.